# How to populate dropdown list from mysql after replaceWith() function using jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have an `input` that can be changed into a `select` when a value is selected. The select has an id of `type`. I tried using the `replaceWith()` method, and it worked.

How can I populate the `select` with options from my database after calling `replaceWith()`?

```php
<?php
  include 'connection.php';

  $result = mysqli_query($cn, "SELECT id, product FROM table_product ORDER BY product ASC");

  $data = array();
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
  {
    $data[] = $row;
  }
?>
```

```html
<input type="text" name="product" class="form-control" id="product" placeholder="Input Product" required>
```

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#type').change(function(){
    $("#product").replaceWith('<select type="text" name="product" class="form-control" id="product" placeholder="Input Product" required><option value="" disabled selected hidden>Select Product</option></select>');

    $.getJSON("getproduct.php", function(data) {
      $.each(data, function(index, item) {
        items += "<option value='" + item.ID + "'>" + item.Name + "</option>";
      });
      $("#product").html(items); 
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Assuming there is only one `#product` element in the DOM, and the AJAX request is successful, your code should work fine. Try checking the console for errors.

Comment: Thanks for your response. There are more than one #product in the DOM.

Comment: Then that is your problem. Id attributes have to be unique. Create a new id for this select, or use common classes and relate the elements to each other by traversing the DOM.

Comment: I changed the id into #product2 but still not working.

Comment: What is the response from getproduct.php ?

Comment: This is my result from getproduct.php [["1121","Pencil"]]